# How can I disable the shadow dropping behind a sub-menu in GWT MenuBar?

Tags: gwt, shadow, menubar, submenu

I created a [MenuBar](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html) with collapsing sub-menus using Googles GWT like in this example: [GWT Showcase MenuBar](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwMenuBar)

Hovering over a MenuItem opens a sub-menu if defined. The sub-menu drops a non-css3 shadow, which doesn't fit into my ui design, because I'm using a differently styled css3 box-shadow.

At first sight one doesn't seem to be able to disable this shadow in some property... does someone have an idea how to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MenuBar popup is a 9-box - a table with 9 cells. The boxes in the table have style names matching the pattern `.menuPopup[Position]` and `.menuPopup[Position]Inner`, where `Position` is, for example, `TopLeft`, `BottomRight`, `Left`, etc.

If you copied the styles from the Showcase it should be sufficient to remove all references to the cells that are not `.menuPopupMiddleCenter` or `.menuPopupMiddleCenterInner` to remove the drop shadow you see.